# Why would a named range not work?

Tags: excel

I am having an interesting problem with a pretty simple excel SUMIF statement. The SUMIF uses a named range(represents a single cell only) as its criteria i.e. `=SUMIF(A1:A100,*named range*,B1:B100)`. For some reason the result of this SUMIF statement doesn't change when the named range value is changed. I fixed the problem by referencing the specific cell, but am wondering why this problem would be occurring.

A few things to mention:

I made sure that cell calculations were automatic.
Also this sheet was copied into the workbook, but the formulas were added after.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You would need to post sample data that you're feeding into the `SUMIF` function in order for us to truly troubleshoot it. In general, if the result of the `SUMIF` function doesn't change, it most likely that the condition is returning false, and therefore not adding that to the sum. Without actual data, the best we can do is ask (1) what is in the range? (2) and how are you changing the range, and what data is in that new range, etc.

Comment: Presumably your formula really has quotes around the * concatenated to the Named Range  If so it works OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the named range doesn't refer to to the original named reference in the workbook you copied the sheet from